# Android 10 perform intent to settings live captioning

Tags: android, android-10.0

I would like to make a Intent to send the user to the settings screen which it has the switch to enable the Live Captioning introduced by Android 10, is there any way to to this intent?

The manual way is as described in this [post](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-live-caption-in-android-10/)

I've tried this intent:

```
startActivity(Intent(ACTION_CAPTIONING_SETTINGS));
```

But it redirects to general captions activation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only intent i found was working is

```
startActivity(Intent("com.android.settings.action.live_caption"))
```

(category DEFAULT if you want to pass that as well)

I found this by finding the top activity when I had it open on my phone with adb and then inspecting the settings application to find intents matching the activity name.

Be aware, this is not an offical way to open this dialog. It may be subject to change and is very likely to differ between devices.

I could not find an Intent which is more general, so I'm assuming there's no offical way to open the activity.